# Does walking, running and jogging improve the health?

Tags: running, exercise, jogging, walking

I am a working person and I don't do much exercise except I go for walking, running and jogging every week.

Will it improve my health or not and how?

Comment: What do you mean by "improve my health"?  What specific improvement(s) would you like?

Answer (score 4):

Well, yes this improves your general health. You don't need to work out every day to be a healthy person. The only reason many people work out is because a lot of people have jobs in which they sit in an office all day.

To make up for the lack of movement we get throughout the day, we go to a gym to work out, or go running or cycling. A few thousand years a go we didn't go to a gym because we had to physically run in order to get food, we had to hunt. These days we don't, so we need another form of physical activity in order to remain healthy.

Answer (score 1):

Regular running or jogging offers many health benefits. Running can: help to build strong bones, as it is a weight-bearing exercise. It helps to maintain a healthy weight.
The bottom line is that the harder you work, the more calories you'll burn, which is the key to losing weight. Jogging burns more calories per minute than walking, so you can lose weight faster by learning to love running — here's an eight-week plan to get you up to speed.

Comment: Looks like the 8 week plan didn't get attached!

Answer (score 0):

Training (working out) and exercising are not the same thing. You must exercise every day. This does not mean working out, but you should move your body. Walking is a great exercise, and maybe it is one of the best. You can also do some simple stuff such as Jumping Jacks.

However, running and jogging is somewhat different. Although there are many people who claim to run everyday and have a good health; running may harm you in the long run, if you are overdoing it. Being said that, I really believe that any healthy person should be able to run a certain distance (which can change for everyone).

So, 1 day of serious strength training may be enough for an average joe, but you (everyone) should try to add walking to his/her daily routine, such as 8k-10k steps.